# Group all the error messages of a Formset in one only error message (Django)

Tags: django, message, formset

I've tried to find an answer for this but it has been impossible for me (documentation, stackoverflow...).

I have a dynamic form with only two fields, URL and Password. There is a button that add more rows of both fields, too.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEn2U.jpg

I would like to show only one error for all the fields in the top of the formset, for example. Is it possible? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<ul>
{% for error in form.errors %}
    <li>{{ error }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```